# How do I create a compound unique autoincrementing field in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I would like to create a schema where I can set a specific name for a user, for example a display name that many people can have, while also allowing people to add them based on that name. My solution is to save that name into a model with two fields, one of which is the name itself, the second one having an id that represents the number of times that name is being used currently.

```
var DisplayName = new Schema({
   account: {
       type: ObjectId,
       ref: 'Account',
   },
   name: {
       type: String,
       trim: true,
       required: true,
   },
   number: {
       type: Number,
       required: true,
   }
});
```

is what I have, but I would like to be able to just say

```
var displayName = new DisplayName({
   name: 'name',
   account: req.user.id
});

displayName.save();
```

and it would automatically set the field for me?

EDIT: I realize there wasn't enough detail in the original question:

I'd like to use mongoose's built-in post-save handlers to generate this field for me on creation. It shouldn't be updated after its created, only set the first time.

Comment: you need the number field to be auto increment for every save and update on this collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as shown below to do that thing.

```js
function saveDisplayName(schema) {
 var query = DisplayName.find({name: schema.name});

 query.then(function(results) {

  var userNumber = 1;
  if (results.length < 1) {
   return userNumber;
  }
  for (var i = 0;  i <= results.length - 1; i++) {
   var result = results[i];

   if (userNumber <= result.number) {
    userNumber = result.number + 1;
   }
   if (i == results.length - 1) {
    return userNumber;
   }
  }
 }).then(function(userNumber) {
  schema.number = userNumber;

  var displayName = new DisplayName(schema);

  return displayName.save();
 }).then(function(data) {
  console.log('Data saved', data)
 }).then(null, console.log);
}
```

Comment: I know that a function is available, also that I can add a post-save handler, I'd just like to know if mongoose has a built-in one

Comment: I don't know if mongoose has it.